# Conditional Content directives appearing in output when using quarto and gt

Tags: quarto, gt

I am trying to create a document which rotates a gt() generated table into landscape when rendered as a pdf. Using conditional content works but I am getting 'garbage' in the output. For example when rendering as html I see a spurious back tick at the beginning and `{=html} at the end. The pdf render is clean. Attached is the code to reproduce and a marked up image of the problem.

[Result of code when rendering as html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agAGH.jpg)

````html
---
title: "conditional test"
format:
  html:
     abstract: "Demonstrates spurious output for html"
  pdf:
    abstract: "pdf output is clean"
    number-sections: true 
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 2
    header-includes:
       - \usepackage{rotating}    
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(gt) 

table <- data.frame(col1=letters, col2=LETTERS) |> head(3)  |> gt() 
#table <- "Simple text which renders cleanly."
```

:::{.content-visible when-format="pdf"}
`r sprintf("\\begin{sidewaysfigure}")`
`r table` pdf
`r sprintf("\\end{sidewaysfigure}")`
:::

:::{.content-visible when-format="html"}
`r table` html
:::
````

I was expecting the circled content to not appear in the output

Comment: I would file an issue on github, if you use not an inline r code, but an r chunk it works as expected.

Comment: thank you for the workaround. I will following up on github.